# How to traverse an multidimensional array to write it in a delimited file. (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, xls

I've an array "$results" that contains result-set which is scraped from web page using regular expressions.
I'm bit confused in traversing the array to  write the whole data of array in .csv file.

here is output of array after printing it in following way.

```
print_r ($results);    //printing the array
```

Output

```
 Array
    (
        [fullName] => Ogdensburg Walmart Store #2092
        [street1] => 3000 Ford Street Ext
        [city] => Ogdensburg
        [state] => NY
        [zipcode] => 13669
        [phone] => (315) 394-8990
        [latitude] => 44.7083
        [longitude] => -75.4564
    )
    Array
    (
        [fullName] => Evans Mills Walmart Supercenter Store #5497
        [street1] => 25737 Us Route #11
        [city] => Evans Mills
        [state] => NY
        [zipcode] => 13637
        [phone] => (315) 629-2124
        [latitude] => 44.0369
        [longitude] => -75.8455
    )
    Array
    (
        [fullName] => Watertown Walmart Supercenter Store #1871
        [street1] => 20823 State Route 3
        [city] => Watertown
        [state] => NY
        [zipcode] => 13601
        [phone] => (315) 786-0145
        [latitude] => 43.9773
        [longitude] => -75.9579
    )
```

I've only worked with simple arrays, can anybody give me hint how to traverse `$results` array to write it in .csv file or .xls file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
$fp = fopen("file.csv","w");
foreach((array)$results as $val) {
   fwrite($fp,implode(";",$val)."\r\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```

few things to say:

- the `"\r\n"` is needed to properly change the line
- while the most **common** separator is the comma `(,)`, i find that some 
  apps like microsoft excel 2010 doesnt like it and instead `put the whole line in a cell`; instead the `semicolon` worked in this case.
- i always had problems with [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), so instead im going with this.

**EDITED:**

```
    $fp = fopen("file.csv","w");
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_results.do?serviceName=&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&rx_dest=%2Findex.gsp&sfsearch_single_line_address=K6T');
    preg_match_all('/stores\[(\d+)\] \= \{/s', $contents, $matches);        
    foreach ($matches[1] as $index) {       
        preg_match('/stores\[' . $index . '\] \= \{(.*?)\}\;/s', $contents, $matches);
        preg_match_all('/\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\' \: ([^\,]*?)\,/s', $matches [1], $matches);
        $c = count ($matches [1]);
        $results = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)  {
            $results [$matches [1] [$i]] = trim($matches [2] [$i], "\'");
        }
        fwrite($fp,implode(";",array_values($results))."\r\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

**EDITED 2:**

to write `only specific columns` in the .csv file you need to **avoid** adding them in your
results array() **OR** unset-ting them after, like here:

```
...
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)  {
    $results [$matches [1] [$i]] = trim($matches [2] [$i], "\'");
}
unset( $results["weekEndSaturday"] );
unset( $results["recentlyOpen"] );
.. go on, renove the non-desired values ..
fwrite($fp,implode(";",array_values($results))."\r\n");
```

Comment: it gives the warning: "implode(): Invalid arguments passed".  and there is no data written in file.csv , can you please tell me what should i change so that it can work properly.

Comment: i suspect that your array is somewhat different from the one i grabbed from your post and tested. Please echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo"</pre>"; in your post (edit) and sample source to get it better.. tx

Comment: i want to write only selected columns in cvs file, can i use some filter to skip last few variables of array.................. what should i change in following  line to write selected variables of each row explicitly.........................................................................fwrite($fp,implode(",",array_values($results))."\r\n");

Answer (score 2):

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($results as $row) {
   fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

Try with the parseCSV class, http://www.coursesweb.net/php-mysql/parsecsv_pc

Can easily read CSV data, also convert 2D array to CSV.